# Finding random number assignment while type casting long datatype into String in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, type-conversion

I am facing issue in Pyspark wherein one of the columns assigns random number while type conversion from long to string type. The column comes from another source and it has length up to 17 digits (length ranging from 10 to 17, not fixed).

For example, when this long type =40851611000001100 gets converted into string it is resulting as 40851611000001102. I have tried .cast(T.StringType()), long  to decimal , decimal to string conversion, format_number - it did not work.

Expect it to convert into the same 40851611000001100 in string format

Comment: not able to replicate the issue using the example in the question.

Comment: Please check if this is useful. Consider this column is labelled as code with value 40851611000001100 (long type)


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("code", F.col("code").cast(T.StringType()))  

I get result as 40851611000001102 after this long to string conversion

Comment: see [this](https://imgur.com/a/Ivyse0D). unable to replicate your issue.

Comment: Thank you for checking. Sorry I could not access the link you have provided. Please check the below

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TypeCastingExample").getOrCreate()
# Sample DataFrame with a LongType column containing a large integer
data = [(40851611000001100)]
columns = ["long_column"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(columns)
df_casted = df.withColumn("string_column", expr("format_string('%s', long_column)"))
df_casted.show(truncate=False)